# Sentence matching with gensim word2vec: manually populated model doesn't work

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I'm trying to solve a problem of sentence comparison using naive approach of summing up word vectors and comparing the results. My goal is to match people by interest, so the dataset consists of names and short sentences describing their hobbies. The batches are fairly small, few hundreds of people, so i wanted to give it a try before digging into doc2vec.

I prepare the data by cleaning it completely, removing stop words, tokenizing and lemmatizing. I use pre-trained model for word vectors which returns adequate results when finding similarities for some test words. Also tried summing up the sentence words to find similarities in the original model - the matches do make sense. The similarities would be around general sense of the phrase.

For sentence matching I'm trying the following: create an empty model

```
b = gs.models.Word2Vec(min_count=1, size=300, sample=0, hs=0)
```

Build vocab out of names (or person id's), no training

```
#first create vocab with an empty vector
test = [['test']]
b.build_vocab(test)
b.wv.syn0[b.wv.vocab['test'].index] = b.wv.syn0[b.wv.vocab['test'].index]*0

#populate vocab from an array
b.build_vocab([personIds], update=True)
```

Summ each sentence's word vectors and store the results into the model for a corresponding id

```
#sentences are pulled from pandas dataset df. 'a' is a pre-trained model i use to get vectors for each word

def summ(phrase, start_model):
    '''
    vector addition function
    '''
    #starting with a vector of 0's
    sum_vec = start_model.word_vec("cat_NOUN")*0
    for word in phrase:
        sum_vec += start_model.word_vec(word)
    return sum_vec

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    try:
        personId = row["ID"]
        summVec = summ(df.iloc[i,1],a)
        #updating syn0 for each name/id in vocabulary
        b.wv.syn0[b.wv.vocab[personId].index] = summVec
    except:
        pass
```

I understand that i shouldn't be expecting much accuracy here, but the t-SNE print doesn't show any clustering whatsoever. Finding similarities method also fails to find matches (<0.2 similarity coefficient basically for everything). [[image: ]plot of the entire model[1]]

Wondering if anyone has an idea of where did i go wrong? Is my approach valid at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code, as shown, neither does any `train()` of word-vectors (using your local text), nor does it pre-load any vectors from elsewhere.  So any vectors which do exist – created by the `build_vocab()` calls – will still just be in their randomly-initialized starting locations, and be useless for any semantic purposes.

Suggestions:

- either (a) train your own vectors from your text, which makes sense if you have a good quantity of text; or (b) load vectors from elsewhere. But don't try to do both. (Or, in the case of the code above, neither.)
- The `update=True` option for `build_vocab()` should be considered an expert, experimental option – only worth tinkering with if you've already had things working in simpler modes, and you're sure you need it and understand all the implications.
- Normal use won't ever explicitly re-assign new values into the `Word2Vec` model's `syn0` property - those are managed by the class's training routines, so you never need to zero them out or modify them. You should tally up your own text summary vectors, based on word-vectors, outside the model in your own data structures.

Comment: thanks for your answer! i was confused regarding syn0 functionality because i saw this update recommendation in some google groups discussion. I got an advice to try scipy.spatial.distance.cosine() for similarity calculation and that worked just fine for me.